# User isn't viewing the right Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, page-layout, site-contents

I'm having trouble with my Master Page and Page Layouts

**Problem:**

I have a Master Page and Page Layout that I have altered from the defaults.  The changes that I made were:

- Changing the name of the browser tabs to reflect the company name
- Removing the side navigation bar from the site

My problem is that one of my users, maybe even more, is experiencing what seems to be like a problem with loading the Master Page (or using an older non-edited version). The user is seeing the side site contents navigation bar as well as the wrong name for the tabs, which I have changed/removed.

- What could be the problem?
- Why is he not seeing what I'm seeing?

Help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are they checked in as major versions, published, and approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check that you actually set the site to use the new master page
- Check in/publish/approve the new master page you made otherwise not everyone will see it.

Comment: I checked them out and checked them back in and it fixed the problem.  Thanks!